# How to carry a value across function call chains

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have the following data structure and functions:

```
data Settings = Settings { dbName :: String } deriving Show

-- username to user id lookup
getUserId :: Settings -> String -> Int
getUserId settings username = 1

-- checks permission for a given user id
hasPermission :: Settings -> Int -> Bool
hasPermission settings userId = True
```

I'd like to be able to chain `getUserId` and `hasPermission` with some syntactic sugar without having to carry instance of `Settings` as I chain the function calls. Something like this:

```
main = do
  let _permission = Settings{dbName="prod"} >>= getUserId "bob" >> hasPermission
  print _permission
```

This (obviously) does not work.

Any go-to patterns for this this?

Comment: This looks like the reader monad to me, but it wouldn't be pretty, exactly.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/the-reader-monad-part-1-1e4d947983a8

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to address such concerns is, in my opinion, to use **partial application**, like this:

```
main = do
  let settings = Settings { dbName="prod" }
  let getUserId' = getUserId settings
  let hasPermission' = hasPermission settings
  let _permission = hasPermission' $ getUserId' "bob"
  print _permission
```

If you put the 'common' argument last, however, you can also use the built-in **reader monad** instance:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let getPermission = (flip getUserId) "bob" >>= (flip hasPermission)
  print $ getPermission $ Settings { dbName="prod" }
```

Here `getPermission` is a local function with the type `Settings -> Bool`. Typically, I consider the first option (partial application) to be simpler and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called [implicit parameters](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#implicit-parameters), which has somewhat gone out of style lately, but I believe it is still supported, which offers a nice solution for this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}

data Settings = Settings { dbName :: String } deriving Show

getUserId :: (?settings :: Settings) => String -> Int
getUserId username = 1

hasPermission :: (?settings :: Settings) => Int -> Bool
hasPermission userId = True

main = do
    let ?settings = Settings { dbName = "prod" }
    print $ hasPermission (getUserId "bob")
```

See also the [implicit configurations](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/tr-15-04.pdf) paper, which explores this problem in quite some depth, and its corresponding library, [`reflection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection).